# ¿Cómo controlar la View desde la Viewmodel?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

Para hacer algunas pruebas, tengo el siguinte evento en el code-behind, que pertence a la clase CreateAnAccount:

```
    private void CreateAccount(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        CreatingAccountGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
        AccountCreatedGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
```

El cual esconde un grid, para mostrar otro grid.

Como estoy trabajando con MVVM, quiero hacer lo mismo solo que desde el Viewmodel. Y lo estoy haciendo de la siguinte manera:

```
using (LoginServiceEntities context = new LoginServiceEntities())
      {
         CreateAnAccount ca = new CreateAnAccount();
         context.CreatingAnAccount(FirstName, LastName, UserName, Password, EMailAddress, Gender);

         ca.CreatingAccountGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Hidden;
         ca.AccountCreatedGrid.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;

         CleanProperties();
         context.SaveChanges();
         context.Dispose();
       }
```

Creo el objeto de la clase de diseño, y llamo al objeto especifico que quiero usar; aparete mente para que funcione de la misma mandera que en el code-behind. Pero el problema que tengo, es que cuando se ejecuta el codigo desde el Viewmodel, no ocurre el cambio del grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si estás trabajando con MVVM deberías tener en cuenta que el ViewModel nunca debe tener conocimiento de la vista, y por lo tanto jamás debes tratar eventos de la vista desde el ViewModel.

Dicho esto, sí que puedes tener ciertas propiedades que sean las que a posteriori determinen si se ven unos elementos y otros.

Sobre la forma correcta de hacer esto hay muchas teorías. La fácil es poner a la propiedad el tipo Visibility y enlazar directamente con el Binding la propiedad Visibility de tu Grid.

La forma correcta sería más  bien crear las propiedades del ViewModel como boolean, ya que el ViewModel no debe conocer ningún detalle de la Vista, y en la vista usar un converter que pase el boolean a Visibility. En este enlace tienes el converter ya hecho de serie en el .NET: https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.controls.booleantovisibilityconverter(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: ¡Muy buena observación, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Si estas usando MVVM, considera la propiedad OnPropertyChanged, esta es la que indica si hay un cambio. También seria útil ver el XAML, y el como estas manejando el evento.

Answer (score 0):

La propiedad defínela a nivel de clase, algo así:

```
private Visibility _creatingAccountGridVisibility;
public Visibility CreatingAccountGridVisibility
{
   get { return _creatingAccountGridVisibility; }
   set 
   { 
     _creatingAccountGridVisibility = value;
     RaisePropertyChanged("CreatingAccountGridVisibility");
   }
}
```

y cuando quieras cambiar su estado la seteas desde cualquier lugar del ViewModel, ahora bien, respecto a que se reflejen estos cambios de la Propiedad en tus controles, los cambios hechos en el ViewModel no se reflejarán en los controles hasta que le informes a la interfaz que han ocurrido dichos cambios.. para eso se usa la interface INotifyPropertyChanged.

Yo uso "RaisePropertyChanged" que es lo mismo, solo que lo acorté implementando el método en otro lugar:

```
protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
{
    var handler = PropertyChanged;

    if (handler != null)
    {
        handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
```

Y al control le bindeas como visibilidad esta propiedad.